# ProgressDialog does not appear in method onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In an Asyntask, i instantiate a progress Dialog in global variables of Asyntask:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Then, in DoInBackGround, i call "publishProgress", so onProgressUpdate in called.
There, in onProgressUpdate, i have the following code:

```
this.progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
                this.progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                this.progressDialog.setTitle("Iniciando la comunicación");
                this.progressDialog.show();
```

I don´t know why, the progressDialog is never shown. I have tried using Toast with the same context, and it works fine. Although progressDialog not.

---------UPDATE--------------

Finally, I've figure it out using notifications.

Comment: I have already tried it, i doesn´t work

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I implemented your answer, nevertheless, it didn´t work out.

Comment: can you post your update code

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I finally made it with notifications, not ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Organize your `AsyncTask` like this

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ...
        // show the dialog
        this.progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
            this.progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog. STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
           //this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            this.progressDialog.setTitle("Iniciando la comunicación");
            this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        ...
        publishProgress("" + progress);
        ...
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {        
      progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog           
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        ...
    }
}
```

Also you want to public the progress when the `AsyncTask` is running, so you need a `STYLE_HORIZONTAL` `ProgressBar` not `STYLE_SPINNER` `ProgressBar`

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem two years ago. There is something unpredictable behaviour while main UI thread interaction.
The solution I found is to use `Thread` instead of `AsyncTack`.

A quick simple example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

//background code to calculate
//for example
for(int i = 0; i < 100000000L; i++){
myHugeCalc(i);
final int prog = i;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        pbtext.setText("My progress: " + prog);

                    }
                });
}

}).start();
```

Comment: can it use for showing downloading progress as async ?

Comment: @NoorHossain yes

Comment: I don't actually know your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do so...
when you are calling this sync process from your class, start showing the progress dialog there, and `onPostExecute` cancel it.
It will do your work...
but the best practise is to do it in `onPreExecute`